# How to get the first two td in row using jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I want to get the first and second row and get the text or element  on the first two td. I used the td:first but I got all text of the td.  I think I may use nth-childe-selector so I search on the web. [:nth-child() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) . However I don't know how to apply on my code. Can someone tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

```
  function test(Id) {
            
            var panel = $('#' + Id);
            var firstRow = panel.closest('tr');    
            var firstTD = firstRow.find('td:first');   
              alert(firstTD.text());
            var secondRow = firstRow.closest('tr');
             
         

        }
```

Comment: Showing a little HTML here would help make your request more concrete.

Comment: Try running $('#' + Id').find('td') on debug console and work from there?

Comment: `firstRow.closest` is "closest *parent*" - ie goes up the tree - you probably want `secondRow = firstRow.next()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
`let firsttr = $('#test tr:first');` to get first row

and  `let secondtr = $('#test tr:nth-child(2)');` to get second row

and use `find` method to get td

```js
function getFistTdValue(){
  
  let firsttr = $('#test tr:first');
  let firsttd = firsttr.find("td:eq(0)").text();
  
  
  alert(firsttd);
  
   let secondtr = $('#test tr:nth-child(2)');
  let secondtd = secondtr.find("td:eq(0)").text();
  
  alert(secondtd);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table id="test">

  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button onclick="getFistTdValue()">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that :eq is deprecated in jquery 3.4 https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/